# Permission denied after image upload

Tags: php

I've got a image upload script that works on my Apache on IIS development server, but on the Apache Lunix live server, although the images are uploaded correctly and the MySQL database is updated correctly, I can't view the images.

Viewing the HTML source, checking both the FTP files and the database values, all look OK.

But the image doesn't show, just the white box with the red cross in the corner.

If I try to copy the shortcut of the image and open it in a separate window, I get the following:

I'm not sure what to try next, it seems strange that the files/database/source look good but it just won't show!

I've tried both `$HTTP_POST_FILES` and `$_FILES` to upload the images, but both have the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the File Permission for images you are uploading, You Apache Server doesn't have permissions to read the image file.

So usually people have Apache Server run as a particular user, which has read (may be write ) access to such content

Comment: OK, how do I do that? I've looked at chmod, where I set the image path, copy it to the server (which works), then change the permissions for that file?: $path1= "../../../../Images/Items/$prod_title/Shop_Thumb/".$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'][0];
copy($HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][0], $path1);
// Read and write for owner, read for everybody else
chmod($path1, 0644); But this doesn't seem to work . . .?

Comment: can you paste the upload code, changing the permissions for the upload folder also might work