# php copy function, failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, permissions, upload

I am trying to upload image on server, below is script that I found on Internet and in worked locally, when I deployed code and database is gives me "failed to open stream: Permission denied" error.

```
<?php
//define a maxim size for the uploaded images in Kb
 define ("MAX_SIZE","5000"); 

//This function reads the extension of the file. It is used to determine if the file  is an image by checking the extension.
 function getExtension($str) {
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }

//This variable is used as a flag. The value is initialized with 0 (meaning no error  found)  
//and it will be changed to 1 if an errro occures.  
//If the error occures the file will not be uploaded.
 $errors=0;

    //reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];

    //if it is not empty
    if ($image) 
    {
    //get the original name of the file from the clients machine
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
    //if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and will not  upload the file,  
    //otherwise we will do more tests
 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png")) 
        {
        //print error message
            echo '<h1>Nepoznata vrsta fajla!</h1>';
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {
//get the size of the image in bytes
 //$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is the temporary filename of the file
 //in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
 $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

//compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
    echo '<h1>To large file!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
}

//we will give an unique name, for example the time in unix time format
$image_name=time().'.'.$extension;
//the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images folder)
$newname="Content/Images/".$image_name;
//we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead
//$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);

$copied = copy('$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);

//echo $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'].'<br/>';
//echo $_FILES['image']['name'];

if (!$copied) 
{
    echo '<h1>Error occurred!</h1>';
    $errors=1;
}}}


//If no errors registred, print the success message
 /*if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
    {
    echo "<h1>You have successfully uploaded image.</h1>";
}*/

 ?>
```

I saw some answerers from stackoverflow like [answers1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272233/copy-function-doesnt-work) and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062268/permission-denied-after-image-upload) but I am not sure how to do that? Is there any other suggestion?

thanks.

Comment: you should post **complete** error message, not only stub

Comment: you should also use `move_uploaded_file()` instead of `copy()`.

Comment: I just wrote something sort to overwrite error message in Bosnian

Comment: well, write it back in english. don't you understand? Asking such question, **you should post complete error message**. Because in contains vital information on the error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure that the system user running php and executing this script has write permission for the directory where you are attempting to store the file.

Comment: In your ftp client (or web-based file manager), you should be able to right-click on the folder and see an option for attributes or permissions. From there, 777 permission simply means that Owner, Group and Public can all Read, Write and Execute. Make sure to only change this permission on your `tmp` folder, as you do not want to grant write access to every folder.

Comment: @eomeroff chmod -R 777 path on your terminal

Comment: fyi 777 stands for "i don't even care. let's go"

Answer (score 1):

The Folder You Trying To Copy Your Files Must Have Same Permission As Your PHP User.(apache user if your server is apache)

./
drwxrwxr-x  root   root   Application
drwxrwxr-x  apache apache FilesystemDir

Answer (score 1):

if you also can not create file in destination folder, and you already put permission on it 755 please check the following:

If your file is: /path/to/test-in.txt

You should have X permission on:

- /path
- /path/to
- and read permission on /path/to/test-in.txt

Check more details here
[fopen() fails to open stream: permission denied, yet permissions should be valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311256/fopen-fails-to-open-stream-permission-denied-yet-permissions-should-be-valid)

Answer (score 0):

Your copy command appears to have syntax errors:

```
$copied = copy('$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
               ^--- extra quote?
```

If you're trying to do something like

```
$copied = copy("$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']", $newname);
```

it won't work anyways. PHP's parser isn't gready, and will see that as

```
$_FILES['image'] -> array
['tmp_name'] -> string
```

and try to do

```
$copied = copy("Array['tmp_name']" ....);
```

And in any case, you should use move_uploaded_file() to handle moving uploaded files, rather than `copy()`. m_u_l has extra checks to make sure no one's tampered with the file in the time between the upload completed and your script trying to move it.

Comment: So this line should go $copied = copy("Array['tmp_name']", $newname); ?

Comment: I just tried and it does not work. It says: Warning: copy(/tmp/someImg.jpg) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...

Comment: He means that you can omit the first apostrophe like this `$copied = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);`

Comment: Most likely the webserver doesn't have permission to write to the 'Content/Images' directory. You should check that whatever userID the server's running under has write permissions there.

Comment: It works now, thanks both, thanks for telling me what he meant.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of the above has solve my problem.
In fact the directories, and files has the good right for user php (=='www-data'). 
But a

```
dump(exec("whoami")); // returns 'another'
```

helps identify that php user was not the awaited one ('www-data') but was 'another'.

Some program has edited the /etc/apache2/envvars

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=another
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=another
```

Put back www-data instead,

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

and restart apache has solve everything.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hopes that could help