# fopen() fails to open stream: permission denied, yet permissions should be valid

Tags: php, linux, permissions, io, fopen

So, I have this error:

```
Warning: fopen(/path/to/test-in.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Performing `ls -l` in the directory where `test-in.txt` is produces the following output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 $USER $USER 1921 Sep  6 20:09 test-in.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 $USER $USER    0 Sep  6 20:08 test-out.txt
```

In order to get past this, I decided to perform the following:

```
chgrp -R www-data /path/to/php/webroot
```

And then did:

`chmod g+rw /path/to/php/webroot`

Yet, I still get this error when I run my php5 script to open the file. Why is this happening? I've tried this using LAMP as well as cherokee through CGI, so it can't be this.

Is there a solution of some sort?

**Edit**

I'll also add that I'm just developing via localhost right now.

**Update - PHP `fopen()` line**

```
$fullpath = $this->fileRoot . $this->fileInData['fileName'];

$file_ptr = fopen( $fullpath, 'r+' );
```

I should also mention I'd like to stick with Cherokee if possible. What's this deal about setting file permissions for Apache/Cherokee?

Comment: And what users is the web server running as and does it have permission to open the file?

Comment: it's running as  my user. As for the second, I can `cat` the text file without any errors, if that helps.

Comment: Are you sure - port 80 is a privileged port and I doubt you can open it. Please add the PHP line as well

Comment: Can you please write down the permission on EVERY directory on the REAL file path?

Comment: Just change permission. In linux host right click on the file and click on the change permissions. Then make all permissions enable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check if the user that PHP runs under have "X" permission on every directory of the file path.
It will need it to access the file

If your file is: `/path/to/test-in.txt`
You should have X permission on:

- `/path`
- `/path/to`

and read permission on `/path/to/test-in.txt`

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks. It looks like `chgrp -R <group> </path/to/dir>` isn't as thorough as I thought...

Answer (score 2):

Another reason of this error may be that the directory of file does not exist.

I just add php code before fopen:

```
if(!file_exists(dirname($file))) 
    mkdir(dirname($file));
```

This help me out.