# Getting an error when I try to download images from a url with CURL

Tags: php, curl

Hello everyone i'm kinda new to PHP and I want to try and download an image URL into a file on my taskbar. I found a small code on stackoverflow that let's me do this but when I try it out I get the error  `fopen(): failed to open stream: Permission denied in`. I looked on the internet about this error code and it said like that I had to give it permission to able to save the pictures in the file, but I don't really know on how to that.This is the code that I have found:

```
function saveImage(){
    $imageFolder = "C:\Users\kemal\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Parfume";
    $ch = curl_init('https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/e/e4/Goku_arrives_colored.PNG/revision/latest?cb=20210204093245');
    $fp = fopen($imageFolder, 'w');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

these are the errors that i'm getting
[image: This is the error that i'm getting]

also tried to use this code instead of curl, but I get the same error(permission denied):

```
$url = 'http://example.com/image.php';
$img = '/my/folder/flower.gif';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Does your webserver have the permission to write to that given folder? Is this a problem of cURL itself?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311256/fopen-fails-to-open-stream-permission-denied-yet-permissions-should-be-valid but could get far because I didn't know on where to give the permission

Comment: @NicoHaase I also tried using this code `$url = 'http://example.com/image.php';
$img = '/my/folder/flower.gif';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));` but it gave the same error that the permission is denied. I also updated my question with the code that I have tried

Comment: That looks obvious - if you are using Windows (which I would assume, as the first image path looks like that), you cannot write to a Unix folder

Comment: So, `Parfume` is the _file_ name you want to write to? Or is that a folder?

Comment: @brombeer that is the file where I want the pictures to be safed

Comment: A _file_ where you want to save the _pictures_? Multiple files into one _file_? If it is indeed a _file_, for clarity's sake I'd rename `$imageFolder` to `$imageFile`. Set the permissions of that file using the usual way in Windows (right-click -> Properties -> Permissions I think)

Comment: You also don't seem to actually do anything with the cURL response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're running php on Apache HTTP server.

First thing I'd try is to set your $imageFolder path to a folder within the apache2/htdocs folder as the process should have write access to that. If that works then you'd need to set permissions on the original target folder to include the user that the apache process is running under.  For obvious reasons webservers are normally fairly restricted as to what folders they can read and write to.

For the second example ($img = '/my/folder/flower.gif'), you'll probably find that path doesn't exist.

Comment: I moved the `$imagefolder` path so it is in the www file from wamp, so next to the index.php file where I do the coding. But the weird thing is I gave everyone full access on the folder and it still saying to give it permission

Comment: So does it work when $imageFolder is pointing to the www folder or are you still having the error? Sorry, it's a bit unclear.

Comment: No i'm still having the same error I litteraly tried `$imageFolder = "C:\wamp64\www\Fragrances\Images"; 
` this and I have tried doing it like this ` $imageFolder = "Images"; ` but they both give the same error

Comment: You can't `fopen` a folder, add the _file name_ you want to open

Comment: I think brombeer has it. You're trying to write to a folder and not a file. It's probably failing because it's trying to create a new file but a folder of the same name already exists.

Comment: Ahh I get it after a few hours searching and trying stuff out finally figured it out on how to do it. Thx guys

Comment: Glad you sorted it

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the permissions as an administrator :
right click on Parfume -> Properties -> security -> change Permissions !

Comment: I Already did this tho, I gave everyone in the list full controll. but it is still giving me the error. Do I need to do something on the WAMP server maybe?